# How can I pass data from graph to graph in jetapck compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Here's my code:

```
const val vitaminGraphRoutePattern = "vitamin_graph"
const val vitaminRoute = "vitamin_route"

fun NavController.navigateToVitamin(
    managerToken: String,
    managerId: Int,
    navOptions: NavOptions? = null
) {
    Log.d("vitamin", "navigateToVitamin: $managerToken, $managerId")

    this.navigate(
        route = "$vitaminGraphRoutePattern/$vitaminRoute?$MANAGER_TOKEN=$managerToken&$MANAGER_ID=$managerId",
        navOptions
    )
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalAnimationApi::class)
fun NavGraphBuilder.vitaminGraph(
    nestedGraphs: NavGraphBuilder.() -> Unit
) {
    navigation(
        route = vitaminGraphRoutePattern,
        startDestination = vitaminRoute,
    ) {
        nestedGraphs()
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalAnimationApi::class)
fun NavGraphBuilder.vitaminScreen(
    moveToWelcomeSurvey: (surveyToken: String, answerData: QuestionAnswerData, managerToken: String, managerId: Int) -> Unit,
    moveToResult: (surveyToken: String, managerToken: String, managerId: Int) -> Unit
) {
    composable(
        route = "$vitaminRoute?" +
                "$MANAGER_TOKEN=${MANAGER_TOKEN}" +
                "&$MANAGER_ID=${MANAGER_ID}",
        arguments = listOf(
            navArgument(MANAGER_TOKEN) {
                type = NavType.StringType
                defaultValue = "no value"
            },
            navArgument(MANAGER_ID) {
                type = NavType.IntType
                defaultValue = -1
            }
        )
    ) { backStackEntry ->
        VitaminRoute(
            moveToWelcomeSurvey = { surveyToken, answerData ->
                moveToWelcomeSurvey(
                    surveyToken,
                    answerData,
                    backStackEntry.arguments?.getString(MANAGER_TOKEN) ?: "",
                    backStackEntry.arguments?.getInt(MANAGER_ID) ?: -1
                )
            },
            moveToResult = { surveyToken ->
                moveToResult(
                    surveyToken,
                    backStackEntry.arguments?.getString(MANAGER_TOKEN) ?: "",
                    backStackEntry.arguments?.getInt(MANAGER_ID) ?: -1
                )
            }
        )
    }
}
```

I tried

```
    this.navigate(
        route = "$vitaminGraphRoutePattern?$MANAGER_TOKEN=$managerToken&$MANAGER_ID=$managerId",
        navOptions
    )
```

```
    this.navigate(
        route = "$vitaminGraphRoutePattern/$vitaminRoute?$MANAGER_TOKEN=$managerToken&$MANAGER_ID=$managerId",
        navOptions
    )
```

But they didn't work. And also tried some changes in vitaminGraph with queries. But didn't work. How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean from graph to graph, the code is also incomplete but if you want to pass data to the start route of a graph, you need to pass the input values as default values. So unlike for other routes, instead of passing the data in the route of a composable, pass it as a default value for the route. Something like this:

```
composable(
            route = "vitaminRoute/MANAGER_TOKEN/MANAGER_ID",
            arguments = listOf(
                    navArgument("MANAGER_TOKEN") {
                        type = NavType.StringType; defaultValue = {YOUR ACTUAL VALUE HERE}
                    },
                    navArgument("MANAGER_ID") {
                        type = NavType.IntType; defaultValue = {YOUR ACTUAL VALUE HERE}
                    },
                ),
){
//composable code  
}
```

Comment: Well, this only works in the same graph. Navigation can have group of routes. That's a graph. And I want to pass data from a screen in A group to a screen in B group.